# In Mexico, what do the various colors of curbs mean with respect to parking zones?

Tags: mexico

In the US, I'm accustomed to never parking along a yellow or red curb. yellow meaning a freight loading/unloading zone and red meaning a fire or emergency-access zone.

However, in Mexico I see a plethora of yellow curbs, often in residential neighborhoods, with many people parked along them.  This leads me to think that a yellow curb does not mean "no parking zone" in Mexico.  However, I recently heard of a friend's car being towed for parking in a "yellow zone."

What does a yellow curb signify in Mexico? Can I park there?

Comment: This question appears to be about local traffic laws - applicable to both Mexicans and non-Mexicans alike, and doesn't seem to have anything to do with being an expat.

Comment: @GregHewgill: So you think expats living in Mexico don't need to understand the local laws?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that at all (indeed, I said "applicable to non-Mexicans"). I'm just saying that these local laws don't apply to you any differently just because you're an expat. Anyway, a quick google search using the last line of your question turned up a likely answer straight away.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Well, that's how it's related to being an expat. And googling that line doesn't find an answer for me--it finds answers relevant to the US, but not to Mexico.

Comment: Sometimes Google filters results based on your location, so perhaps that's not surprising. I found a mention of the yellow curb at http://www.sanfelipeguide.com/visiting.html (but it's unclear whether that is a rule for that particular location, or whether it's more widely applicable).

Comment: @GregHewgill: That looks like reasonable information... if you want to make it an answer, it would warrant at least an up-vote if not acceptance... Assuming you're willing to contribute to what you believe to be an off-topic question. :P

Comment: The question could perhaps be acceptable on travel.SE?